# Setting pdftitle and pdfauthor automatically in a LaTeX stylesheet

Tags: latex, stylesheet, hyperref

I use the code below to set the title and author in the pdf document properties.

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {The documents title},
    pdfauthor = {me}
}
```

I would like to automate this by putting it in a stylesheet (.sty) Below is my attempt, but it is not working. The pdf is compiled (pdflatex) with errors. But the pdf document properties remain empty.

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {\@title},
    pdfauthor = {\@author}
}
```

I use the \@title and the \@author variables to create a custom titlepage. So I know those work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you get compile errors, I'm guessing the problem is the `@` character. You need to wrap your code in `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. Another possible problem is that you do this before you execute the `\title` and `\author` commands. A nice fix for this would be to use `\AtBeginDocument`, which would allow you to place this anywhere in your preamble. Note that you have to define the `\title` and `\author` information before `\begin{document}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {\@title},
    pdfauthor = {\@author}
  }
}
\makeatother

\title{Test title}
\author{Sam Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE:** Putting the relevant parts in a style file named `xxx.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{xxx}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{
  \hypersetup{
    pdftitle = {\@title},
    pdfauthor = {\@author}
  }
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Your solution works fine when put in the main tex file. However, it does not work when you put it in a .sty file.

Comment: @Thierry: I have no problems putting this in a `.sty` file.

Comment: After your update, everything works fine. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't `\makeatother` provoke problems if used in a `.sty` file? I would suggest removing `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` from the `.sty` version, as they are not needed there, anyways.

Answer (score 12):

There is the package option `pdfusetitle` for it, see [Make hyperref take pdfinfo from \title and \author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17218/make-hyperref-take-pdfinfo-from-title-and-author).

Comment: Can we change this to the accepted answer?